# Calculate time until the next occurance of 2pm using moment.js

Tags: javascript, string, date, momentjs

I'm looking to use moment.js to calculate the time remaining until the next occurance of 2pm.

So far, based on another script I found I have the following:

```
var getTimeLeft = function(){
  var now = moment();
  var deadline = now.clone().hour(14).minute(0).second(0);
  if(now.isAfter(deadline)) {
    var tomorrow  = moment(new Date()).add(1,'days').hour(14).minute(0).second(0);
    console.log(tomorrow.from(now));
  }else {
    console.log(deadline.from(now));
  }
}
getTimeLeft();
```

If the time is before 2pm this returns the time in a rounded format ie "in 5 hours"

If the time is beyond 2pm this returns "in a day"

How can I edit this script so that if it's run before 2pm I'll get the answer in the format `"4hrs 57mins"` without rounding - and if it's the following day it will do the same, it `"21hrs 2mins"` ?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually **[`moment.from()` method](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/)** returns always a `string` in that format, you can't get its result in `hours` and `minutes` or as `milliseconds`.

**Solution:**

One little trick to display a custom message with `hours` and `minutes` is to use **[`moment.diff()` method](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)**, which returns difference in `milliseconds`, `seconds`, `minutes`, `hours` or `days`.

```
tomorrow.diff(now, "hours") + ' hrs, ' + (tomorrow.diff(now, "minutes") % 60) + ' mins'
```

You just need to specify `hours`/`minutes` as second param of the `.diff()` method, to get the result in the wanted format.

**Demo:**

This is a working demo:

```js
var getTimeLeft = function() {
  var now = moment();
  var deadline = now.clone().hour(14).minute(0).second(0);
  if (now.isAfter(deadline)) {
    var tomorrow = moment(new Date()).add(1, 'days').hour(14).minute(0).second(0);
    console.log(tomorrow.diff(now, "hours") + ' hrs, ' + (tomorrow.diff(now, "minutes") % 60) + ' mins');
  } else {
    console.log(deadline.diff(now, "hours") + ' hrs, ' + (deadline.diff(now, "minutes") % 60) + ' mins');
  }
}
getTimeLeft();
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.7.0/moment.js"></script>
```

**Note:**

Of course you need to add more tests to test for cases when there are only `hours` or only `minutes` as difference.